# Android receiving multiple BLE packets per connection interval

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a device that transmits data to my Android (4.4.2) over a BLE GATT characteristic.  The device sends multiple 20byte packets per connection interval, where each packet has a sequence number.
Lets say the device is sending 4 packets per connection interval, as shown...
|sq1,sq2,sq3,sq4|sq5,sq6,sq7,sq8|..

I notice at the Android end, may calls to onCharacteristicChanged() are coming in like...
|sq4,sq4,sq4,sq4|sq8,sq8,sq8,sq8|...

Does Android support sending multiple packets per connection interval?

Michael

Comment: did you find the answer to it? I also want to know how many packets can be sent per connection. my device and Android is sending and receiving dozens of packets per connection but after (say 50) packets it get slower and eventually gets very very slow which is unexceptionable. Can you give me suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it supports multiple packets per connection interval, but the API is badly designed, and the characteristic value is a shared object, which may be updated by multiple threads. Each notification may be handled in a different thread and they then call `onCharacteristicChanged` on one thread (either set in `connectGatt(...)`, or some unspecified thread for older Android versions. If the connection interval is very small, or the device sends many packets in a single interval, it may happen that before you receive the callback with the first notification it will be overwritten by another.

There are 2 advices I may give:

1. The reference to the value should be obtained as soon as possible, at the beginning of `onCharacteristicChanged` method, as it may soon be changed (by another notification, or write operation). Ref: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/issues/54
2. Don't use `connectGatt(..., Handler)` method, but rather rely on the default handler. If you set a handler, this will add additional time before you receive the callback, so more opportunity for the data to be overwritten. Ref: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/issues/54

The above advices do not guarantee 100% of success, however, but lower the chance of loosing data.

Also, when you write and listen to notification, I recommend splitting that into 2+ characteristics as the characteristic's value is then shared between write and notify operations. Value may be updated before it's sent, and you'll end up sending what was received. Ref: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/issues/60

The iOS API is much better, as the data are set as a parameter to the [`writeValue(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518747-writevalue) and received as value in [`peripheralDidUpdateValueFor(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518708-peripheral). They are not shared.